# how to adjust column size when page width changes in css?

Tags: html, css

In my example below, when page width is > 300px, the two columns span the entire width of the page, however, when the page size decreases below the 300px, the one column can't fill the entire page. How to change that so that one column fits entire page?

```css
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.cols {
  width:50%;
  min-width:300px;
  float:left;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
</div>

<div class="cols">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using Media Queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

You can change css with `@media (max-width: 620px)`.
 Look my example.
Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

```css
html {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.cols {
  width:50%;
  min-width:300px;
  float:left;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
.cols {
  width:100%;
  min-width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
</div>

<div class="cols">
</div>
```